# perform operation on SQL results with same reference

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I'm building a kinda search engine thing.

My query breaks apart a query string and then `SELECT`s for each word from the string all of the reference ids associated with that word.

I have a method of giving a relevance score to each id for each query word. However I am looking for a way of keeping track if my query returns the id multiple times. Could anyone point me in the right directions. I am using PHP and mySQL??

Comment: real S.O questions contain code. and it sounds like your reinventing mysql's full text search -- for some reason.

Comment: We really need to see code in order to understand what you're explaining. If you can add it, flag your question for moderator attention (or just reply to my comment, I'll be here for a while longer) and this can be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use PHP or SQL to achieve this:

a code example (no error checking, assuming you're using mysql api directly - which you shouldn't):

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT ...';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$ids = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $id = $row->id;
    if (array_key_exists($id, $ids)) {
        print 'id '. $id . ' exists';
        continue;
    }
    $ids[$id] = true;
}
?>
```

using SQL you could try a HAVING statement, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM whatevs HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Since I don't know your table layout it's hard to write actually working code/SQL.